# Decimal(0.19) results in very long number?

Tags: python, django

My model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    VAT_CHOICES = [
        (Decimal(0.19), Decimal(0.19)),
        (Decimal(0.07), Decimal(0.07)),
    ]
    vat = models.DecimalField(
        choices=VAT_CHOICES,
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=Decimal(0.19))
```

Parsing `0.19` to a `decimal` number yields a very long number with about 20 decimal places. What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to avoid this?

Do I always have to write e. g. `round(Decimal(0.19), 2)` to get the desired number? I want the precise number `0.19`.

Comment: Try `Decimal("0.19")`. You did nothing wrong, it is just a normal float precision problem.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw to docs ... but I am not sure how to handle this ... is the solution to increase the decimal places to a very high number? use a float field instead? I also want to do some arithmetic operations with user generated numbers, these numbers will be parsed from JSON.

Comment: You should use *strings* here, since by using `Decimal(0.19)` you take a float as initial value, and thus the error is already introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already pointed out, you should use a `str` instead of a `float` as argument to the `Decimal` constructor; the error happens because either `0.19` or `0.07` cannot be converted losslessly to a fixed-point representation with 2 decimal places. Read more in the [`decimal` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal), specifically where it explains `float` as arguments to `Decimal`.

So your model could look like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    VAT_CHOICES = [
        (Decimal('0.19'), Decimal('0.19')),
        (Decimal('0.07'), Decimal('0.07')),
    ]
    vat = models.DecimalField(
        choices=VAT_CHOICES,
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=VAT_CHOICES[0][0])
```

I also used `VAT_CHOICES` for the `default` keyword to reduce redundancy.